# How is this logarithm problem solved?

Tags: logarithms

If $\dfrac{xy\log xy}{x+y} = \dfrac{yz\log yz}{y+z} = \dfrac{zx\log zx}{z+x}$ show that $x^x = y^y = z^z$.

I tried equating to a constant $k$ and adding up

I also tried adding up the numerators and denominators
to find each ratio

But still i am not able to figure out how to reach the final result

Comment: Does it should be $\cdots=\displaystyle\frac{zx\log zx}{z+\color{red}{x}}$?

Comment: Yea oops;My Math Jax application messed it up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite

$$\frac{\log(x)+\log(y)}{\frac1x+\frac1y}=
\frac{\log(y)+\log(z)}{\frac1y+\frac1z}=
\frac{\log(z)+\log(x)}{\frac1z+\frac1x}.$$

Then by the rules of proportions,

$$\frac{\log(x)}{\frac1x}=\frac{\log(y)}{\frac1y}=\frac{\log(z)}{\frac1z}.$$

Comment: Should your last term have been $\dfrac{\log z}{\frac 1 z}$? $\qquad$

Comment: Can i do it by equating the first equation to k

Comment: Which proportion rule is used

Comment: @MichaelHardy: was called on the phone before finishing :)